# Wildcard search people with Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, node.js, facebook-graph-api, wildcard

I'm trying to figure out if its possible to search for people using the Facebook Graph API, even if they're not my friends. (Kind of like the actual Facebook search on the website).

I have a form for creating new customers, and wanted to allow an option to find the customer on person to auto-fill some of the details (and get its photo on the way).

Thought of using FQL but would rather not, since it will expire in a year or so, and I'd rather use the newest set of APIs... But I'm open to FQL solutions if there's no Graph solution possible.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to search for people using the API is explained here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.1

See "Searching":

```
graph.facebook.com/search?q={name-to-search}&type=user
```